# Confusion in notation of the finite double series $\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot j^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

> Evaluate:
>   $$\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} i\cdot j^2$$

- Now I am confused how to evaluate the sum as I think that the question hasn't specified that whether $m>n$ or $n>m$.
- I don't know where the series would terminate.

Could anyone clarify the notation as well as give an expanded version of the above expression?

Comment: The idea is that the inner summation ranges from $1\to n$, and the outer one from $1\to m$. It doesn't matter which is bigger. The series terminates.

Comment: @Don Thousand would you please expand the series for me?

Comment: There will be a total of $m\times n$ terms in the expanded summation.  One for each pair of values of $i,j$ in the range $1,\dots,n$ and $1,\dots,m$ respectively.  For example with $m=n=3$ you have $\sum\limits_{j=1}^3\sum\limits_{i=1}^3 i j^2 = 1\cdot 1^2 + 1\cdot 2^2 + 1\cdot 3^2 + 2\cdot 1^2 + 2\cdot 2^2 + 2\cdot 3^2 + 3\cdot 1^2 + 3\cdot 2^2 + 3\cdot 3^2$

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{m} \sum_{i=1}^{n} ij^2
=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} ij^2\right)
=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \left(j^2\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\right)
=\sum_{j=1}^{m} \left(j^2\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\right)\right)
=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{m} j^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} i\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^m\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ij^2=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m j^2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i$$$$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n j^2\cdot\big(\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2\big)$$$$=\bigg(\frac{m\cdot(m+1)\cdot(2m+1)}6\bigg)\cdot\bigg(\frac{n\cdot(n+1)}2\bigg)$$